Grouping Json with same value of a key with Jolt
I have hard time to understand how to group JSON array using Jolt.
I want to group by "LocationX" and "LocationY" into individual objects in an Array.
Input JSON:
[
  [
    {
      "LocationX": "36.28",
      "LocationY": "-5.29",
      "DataValue": "0.36",
      "DataType": "distance_1"
    },
    {
      "LocationX": "36.28",
      "LocationY": "-5.29",
      "DataValue": "11.0",
      "DataType": "distance_2"
    },
    {
      "LocationX": "36.28",
      "LocationY": "-5.29",
      "DataValue": "10.0",
      "DataType": "distance_3"
    },
    {
      "LocationX": "36.28",
      "LocationY": "-5.29",
      "DataValue": "0.04",
      "DataType": "distance_4"
    },
    {
      "LocationX": "36.28",
      "LocationY": "-5.29",
      "DataValue": "58.82",
      "DataType": "distance_5"
    },
    {
      "LocationX": "36.34",
      "LocationY": "-5.29",
      "DataValue": "0.00",
      "DataType": "distance_1"
    },
    {
      "LocationX": "36.34",
      "LocationY": "-5.29",
      "DataValue": "9.8",
      "DataType": "distance_2"
    },
    {
      "LocationX": "36.34",
      "LocationY": "-5.29",
      "DataValue": "2206",
      "DataType": "distance_3"
    },
    {
      "LocationX": "36.34",
      "LocationY": "-5.29",
      "DataValue": "0.00",
      "DataType": "distance_4"
    },
    {
      "LocationX": "36.34",
      "LocationY": "-5.29",
      "DataValue": "58.28",
      "DataType": "distance_5"
    }
  ]
]

I would like to group by "LocationX" and "LocationY" into individual objects in an Array.
Expected JSON output:
[
  {
    "LocationX": 36.28,
    "LocationY": -5.29,
    "distance_1": 0.36,
    "distance_2": 11.0,
    "distance_3": 10.0,
    "distance_4": 0.04,
    "distance_5": 58.82,
    "Rod":"S" //this is default value for all objects
  },
  {
    "LocationX": 36.34,
    "LocationY": -5.25,
    "distance_1": 0.00,
    "distance_2": 9.8,
    "distance_3": 2206,
    "distance_4": 0.00,
    "distance_5": 58.28,
    "Rod":"S"
  }
]

Could you please help on getting the desired JSON output. Thank you.
16/04/2024
I have new improvements that need to add for the above input json as follows.
Input JSON:
[
  [
    {
      "Name": "03.04.2023",
      "StartTime": "2023-04-03 06:32",
      "SessionData": [
        {
          "LocationX": "36.282466",
          "LocationY": "-5.298164",
          "DataValue": "0.36",
          "DataType": "distance_1"
        },
        {
          "LocationX": "36.282466",
          "LocationY": "-5.298164",
          "DataValue": "11.0",
          "DataType": "distance_2"
        },
        {
          "LocationX": "36.282466",
          "LocationY": "-5.298164",
          "DataValue": "2231",
          "DataType": "distance_3"
        },
        {
          "LocationX": "36.282466",
          "LocationY": "-5.298164",
          "DataValue": "0.04",
          "DataType": "distance_4"
        },
        {
          "LocationX": "36.282466",
          "LocationY": "-5.298164",
          "DataValue": "58.82",
          "DataType": "distance_5"
        },
        {
          "LocationX": "36.278355",
          "LocationY": "-5.290660",
          "DataValue": "0.00",
          "DataType": "distance_1"
        },
        {
          "LocationX": "36.278355",
          "LocationY": "-5.290660",
          "DataValue": "9.8",
          "DataType": "distance_2"
        },
        {
          "LocationX": "36.278355",
          "LocationY": "-5.290660",
          "DataValue": "2206",
          "DataType": "distance_3"
        },
        {
          "LocationX": "36.278355",
          "LocationY": "-5.290660",
          "DataValue": "0.00",
          "DataType": "distance_4"
        },
        {
          "LocationX": "36.278355",
          "LocationY": "-5.290660",
          "DataValue": "58.28",
          "DataType": "distance_5"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
]

Expected Output JSON:
[
  {
    "StartTime": "2023-04-03 06:32",
    "distance_1": "0.36",
    "LocationX": "36.282466",
    "LocationY": "-5.298164",
    "distance_2": "11.0",
    "X_Z_distance": "2231",
    "Y_Z_distance": "0.04",
    "Temp_1": 2189,
    "Distance_Type": "D",
    "Distance_Length": "M"
  },
  {
    "StartTime": "2023-04-03 06:32",
    "distance_1": "0.00",
    "LocationX": "36.278355",
    "LocationY": "-5.290660",
    "distance_2": "9.8",
    "X_Z_distance": "2206",
    "Y_Z_distance": "0.00",
    "Temp_1": 2164,
    "Distance_Type": "D",
    "Distance_Length": "M"
  }
]

Based on the answer I got, I developed following JOLT.
JOLT:
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "Location*": "@(1,LocationX).@(1,LocationY).&",
              "@DataValue": "@(1,LocationX).@(1,LocationY).@DataType"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "Temp_1": "=doubleSum(@(1,distance_3),-42)"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "Distance_Length": "M",
          "Distance_Type": "D"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "ONE"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[]"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "distance_5": ""
      }
    }
  }
]

I want add "StartTime" for each object, and distance_3 and distance_4 into X_Z_distance and Y_Z_distance.
Could you please help on getting the desired JSON output. Thank you

You can partition the objects by LocationX/Y attributes in order to get binary result such as
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "Location*": "@(1,LocationX).@(1,LocationY).&",
          "@DataValue": "@(1,LocationX).@(1,LocationY).@DataType",
          "#S": "@(1,LocationX).@(1,LocationY).Rod" // hardcode desired fixed 
                                                    // value by using # operator
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // pick only one occurrence per each repeating Location arrays
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "ONE"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the object keys while converting whole JSON
    // to array of objects
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[]"
      }
    }
  }
]

the demo on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :


Thank you. Appreciate! @Barbaros Özhan Could you please explain the first shift operation.
If we want to add another hardcoded key and value pair, how we can do it ? Thanks

Hi @casper , nice to help. A dot followed identifier constructs an object(such as @(1,LocationY) ) with the value of that identifier, This way we can put each elements into that common objects based on their values respectively. The integer 1 within @(1,LocationX) represents the level to reach its original place(on the LHS originally) as currently being on the RHS.

Thank you @Barbaros Özhan. I have new improvements that need to add for the input json. I added them into the original question. I built a jolt based on your answer, but there are few items that I couldn't develop. Could you please help on them. Thank you

Kindly you can ask a new question along with reverting the last changes you've made, as the original question is already a completed one @casper
